# Constrained update statements in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to write 3 update statements inside a stored procedure. How can I confirm that the second and third update statements will get executed only when the first update statement is successfully completed?

```
create or replace procedure test
as
begin

update statement1;
commit;

--following block executes only when update 1 is sucessful
update statement2;
commit;

update statement2;
commit;
end;
```

I don't want to check the status of the first update statement with a SQL query as the table which is getting updated - it is too large.

Comment: How do you define 'successful'? That no error occurred; that any rows were actually updated; a specific number were; or something else? (And why are you comitting after each statement - shouldn't all three updates be part of the same transaction?)

Comment: Hi Alex, I just want to make sure that the update executed with no error.

Comment: If it gets an error then the procedure will terminate, as you aren't catching any exceptions - the caller will see whatever error was raised. That is the default behaviour. You don't need to do anything else. Note though that if the *second* update gets an error the same thing happens, but you have commiited the first update so that change is permenant whatever happens later. Make sure that is what you really want.

Comment: Understood. But lets think of a scenario, where no rows gets updated in update statement1. In that case I don't want to proceed with next two statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how many rows were affected by a statement with [the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` implicit cursor attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/sql_cursor.htm#LNPLS01348):

```
create or replace procedure test
as
begin

  update statement1;
  --commit;

  --following block executes only when update 1 is sucessful
  if sql%rowcount > 0 then
    update statement2;
    --commit;

    update statement2;
    --commit;
  end if;
end;
```

If no rows are updated the row count will be zero and the statements inside the `if` will be skipped.

If an actual error occurs [then execution stops anyway](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#LNPLS143).

I've commented out your commit statements because you need to be sure you understand their implications. I would normally expect all of the statemens in a procedure to be part of the same logical transaction, with transaction control handled by the caller (or by *its* caller). If you commit after the first update and get an error on the second then your data may be left in an inconsistent state.

Comment: oh...so simple...that's why you need a second pair of eyes while working on an off-day. :). Thanks mate.